# How to run a multiple AND query with Android Room?

Tags: android, android-room

I have an example use case that requires all supplied conditions to be true. Conditions are supplied by users, therefore are not known until runtime. Ex.

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE [CONDITION 1] AND [CONDITION 2]...AND [CONDITION N]
```

Is there a simple way to express this in Android Room DAO @Query()? I'm currently using `2.1.0-beta01`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Raw Query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery):

```
@Dao
 interface RawDao {
     @RawQuery
     User getFoo(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
 }

 SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE [CONDITION 1] AND [CONDITION 2]...AND [CONDITION N]");
 Foo foo = rawDao.getFoo(query);
```